# Axioms of ordered geometry imply ordered field

Tags: geometry, ordered-fields

My question is almost the same of [Axioms of order in geometry and ordered fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359494/axioms-of-order-in-geometry-and-ordered-fields).
I'm reading the book of Robin Hartshorne,Geometry: Euclid and beyond and i'm having hard time to write down a proof for Proposition 15.3 in particular i don't get the first statement of the proof (which is left almost entirely to the reader) which says: "Since addition corresponds to lay out segment consecutively on the x axis, one can show easily that $a,b\in P\implies a+b\in P$"
I tried to use Pash (B4) and the line separation by i didn't go any further.

[image]

Comment: In my copy of the book Proposition 15.3 is different. Could you please write down its text, or at least add a photo?

Comment: Sure, the statement i mentioned is actually a part of the proof (a hint i would say). I am able to proove the multiplication (i used Pash to get a contraddiction) but i'm not able to proove the sum. What does he mean with "laying out" line segments consecutively?